# run a function again when screen is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm trying to do an animation which runs by clicking on `aside` tag. after this, I want to run the `asideAnime` function again when resizing screen (window).

**this my JS code :**

```
var image_url = $('aside').css('background-image'),image;
// Removing url() or in case of Chrome url("")
image_url = image_url.match(/^url\("?(.+?)"?\)$/);

if (image_url[1]) {
    image_url = image_url[1];
    image = new Image();

    $(image).load(function () {
        var a = image.width;
        var b = image.height;
        var c = $(window).width();
        var d = $(window).height();
        var e = ((d-b)/b); //height inscrease amount ratio
        var f = a+(e*a); //changing width based on height change

        $('aside').click(function(){
            asideAnime(a,b,c,d,e,f);
            $(this).addClass('done');
        });
    });
    image.src = image_url;
}

var asideAnime = function(a,b,c,d,e,f) {
    var g = $('aside').width();
    var h = (e*a); //the amount change in width
    var condition = h > -100;
    $('aside').animate({
        width: f,
        maxWidth: c
    });

    if(condition) {
        $('.main').animate({
            right: -f,
            left: f,
            marginLeft: "0"
        });
    } else {
        $('.main').animate({
            right: "0",
            left: f,
            marginLeft: "0"
        });
    };
}
```

I tried to do this by using `if` statement before the resize function, but it didn't work..

```
if ($('aside').hasClass('done')) {
    $(window).resize(function(){
        asideAnime(a,b,c,d,e,f);
    });
}
```

anybody has any idea ? thanks

**To explain more:**

there is `aside` tag with 30% width and a background image with `background-size:cover` .
by clicking `aside`, the `aside` opens and shows the full image. all this lines of codes are because I'm trying to open `aside` according to the change in bg made by `background-size:cover` while keeping the ratio.

Comment: There actually is something called `screen` in javascript, and resizing it would be difficult as it's the screen, so you should be more specific and always use `window`

Comment: yeah, window resize is important for me..

Answer (score 2):

Once the event handler is attached, it doesn't care about the if condidition surrounding it, it will still always fire when the event happens, so you have to place the condition inside the event handler :

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($('aside').hasClass('done')) {
        asideAnime(a,b,c,d,e,f);
    }
});
```

Also note that placing an event handler inside another event handler is bad practice, as a new resize event handler will be attached **every** time someone clicks the aside, and clicking the aside three times will fire the `asideAnime` function three times when the window is resized.

Comment: I had to use some `var`s out of the first function, so I did like this, but I'm not sure if it's the best way. can you help me optimizing the code format please ?

Comment: Place a console.log inside the asideAnime function and check if it's at least firing on resize, then check the arguments, what are a,b,c,d etc. and where are they coming from

Comment: Looking at your code, you do know the variables a,b,c etc aren't updated on resize, they are only fetched on page load, and stay the same. If you need them to change, you'll have to get them inside the resize handler.

Comment: do you have any suggestion please ?

Comment: Move the variables inside the resize function

Answer (score 0):

Event might not trigger inside if statement.

But, once you bind, the event, it will be always triggered when window is resized. You can check condition ad execute code inside event.

Try:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($('aside').hasClass('done')) {
        asideAnime(a,b,c,d,e,f);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest define var a,b,c,d,e,f globally first.and then trigger click event of `aside` tag on resize of window.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
$(aside).trigger( "click");
});
```

Comment: variables cannot be defined globally because the values are fetched when the background-image URL (like image width or height) is loaded..

Comment: what is problem with defining outside?? i guess you can declae all of then as null/zero and set them on load of image.